# Entity Framework Code First Permission/DB Creation Issues

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am attempting to create a db using EF 5 Code First on SQL Server 2008.  I can create the db using Integrated Security, but I cannot create the db using a custom user.  The code runs the initializer on my home machine for both integrated security and custom user.

The difference in the connection strings is as follows.  In addition to these I changed Data Source to Server and Initial Catalog to Database per [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008).

```
<!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MVCTesting;Integrated Security=False;User Id=Green;Password=******" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MVCTesting;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I compared the SQL users MachineName/LoginName and Green.  They both have server roles of public and sysadmin, neither have any user mappings till a db is created then they are mapped to that db.

In global.asax.cs I have

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MVCTestingInitializer());
        //Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MVCTestingContext>());
        ViewDb();

        //Other setup
    }

    //Init the db by looking up a contact
    private void ViewDb()
    {
        using (var context = new MVCTestingContext())
        {
            var user = context.Contacts.Where(u => u.FirstName.StartsWith("T"));

            var asdf = "";
        }
    }
```

And my initializer is ...

```
public class MVCTestingInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MVCTestingContext>
    {
        protected override sealed void Seed(MVCTestingContext context)
        {
            //Code to init the db
        }
    }
```

Using [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) I am able to verify if the seed is run or not.  When I have integrated security it runs, when I do not the seed does not run.

I have also created an account on the machine, added that account to the AppPool and SQL Server, then retested.  I still see a failure to connect.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'Green'.
```

In a mad fit I decided to add all possible permissions to the user 'Green', I still see the above error.  Does anyone see what I am missing?  I am sure it is so simple and I will smack myself in the head afterwards, but I just do not see it.

If I am really far off, please provide the steps to create a SQL Account/Permissions that I can use in my web config and please include app pool setup.

Thanks,
TJ

Comment: First of all, can you connect to the database using ssms and login green? Do you have ; after password? Did you try to remove IntegratedSecurity=false?

Comment: @Mariusz - Thank you for your comments.  I was right, slap to the head fix.  Logging in with SSMS failed.  The login failure was due to the database setup in Win Auth Mode only.  Changing it to Mixed Mode fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post it as answer :)

If you ever have problem with connecting to db, open ssms and use the same credentials to login to db. This will confirm you have right credentials ;)